# Laravel URL from comain.com/category/slug to domain.com/category

Tags: laravel, url, seo

I searched for answer and didn't find any that will works for me. 
I have table 'articles' where I store articles with 'slug' column.

In my route files I have route:

> Route::get('article/{slug}', 'ArticleController@viewArticle');

that works fine when I type for example /article/some-article-title and article will show, but I want to access from /some-article-title . I'v tried to change route like:

> Route::get('{slug}', 'ArticleController@viewArticle');

And that works when i put this at the end of file, but after all for example WYSIWYG now works (uploading files), and some images stopts work (404 error). I'v tried modyfing .htaccess file and still not working.

Any ideas?

I want to create anchor like this

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/some-title-for-article">some-title-for-article</a>
```

but now the link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/articles/some-title-for-article">some-title-for-article</a>
```

Routes file web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

/* DEPLOY BITBUCKET */
Route::get('/deploy/', 'DeployController@index');
Route::post('/deploy/update',
    ['as' => 'deploy_update', 'uses' => 'DeployController@update']);

/* ADMIN PANEL */

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/admin/', 'AdminController@index');

/* ADMIN USERS */
Route::get('/admin/users', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/admin/users/add/', 'UserController@add');
Route::post('/admin/users/create/', 'UserController@create');
Route::get('/admin/users/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit');
Route::post('/admin/users/update/', 'UserController@update');
Route::delete('/admin/users/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');

/* ADMIN CATEGORIES */
Route::get('/admin/categories', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/admin/categories/add/', 'CategoryController@add');
Route::post('/admin/categories/create/', 'CategoryController@create');
Route::get('/admin/categories/edit/{id}', 'CategoryController@edit');
Route::post('/admin/categories/update/', 'CategoryController@update');
Route::delete('/admin/categories/delete/{id}', 'CategoryController@delete');

/* ADMIN COMMENTS */
Route::get('/admin/comments', 'CommentController@index');
Route::get('/admin/comments/view/{id}', 'CommentController@view');
Route::get('/admin/comments/add/', 'CommentController@add');
Route::post('/admin/comments/create/', 'CommentController@create');
Route::post('/admin/comments/approve/{id}', 'CommentController@approve');
Route::delete('/admin/comments/delete/{id}', 'CommentController@delete');

/* ADMIN ARTICLES */
Route::get('/admin/articles', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('/admin/articles/view/{id}', 'ArticleController@view');
Route::get('/admin/articles/edit/{id}', 'ArticleController@edit');
Route::get('/admin/articles/add/', 'ArticleController@add');
Route::post('/admin/articles/create/', 'ArticleController@create');
Route::post('/admin/articles/approve/{id}', 'ArticleController@approve');
Route::delete('/admin/articles/delete/{id}', 'ArticleController@delete');
Route::post('/admin/articles/update/', 'ArticleController@update');

Route::post('image-upload','ImageController@imageUploadPost');

/* GALLERIES */

Route::get('/admin/galleries', 'GalleryController@index');
Route::get('/admin/galleries/view/{id}', 'GalleryController@view');
Route::get('/admin/galleries/edit/{id}', 'GalleryController@edit');
Route::get('/admin/galleries/add/', 'GalleryController@add');
Route::post('/admin/galleries/create/', 'GalleryController@create');
Route::post('/admin/galleries/approve/{id}', 'GalleryController@approve');
Route::delete('/admin/galleries/delete/{id}', 'GalleryController@delete');
Route::post('/admin/galleries/update/', 'GalleryController@update');

/* IMAGE CONTROLLER */
Route::delete('/admin/images/delete/{id}', 'ImageController@delete');
Route::get('/admin/images/info/{id}', 'ImageController@info');
Route::post('/admin/images/update/', 'ImageController@update');

/* CONTACT FORM */
Route::get('/kontakt/', 'ContactController@index');
Route::post('/kontakt/',
    ['as' => 'contact_send', 'uses' => 'ContactController@send']);

/* GALLERY UPLOAD */
Route::post('/gallery_upload/', 'GalleryController@upload');

/* ARTICLE CONTROLLER */
Route::get('{slug}', 'ArticleController@viewArticle')->name('view.article');
//Route::get('artykuly/{slug}', 'ArticleController@viewArticle');
```

Comment: Post your whole routes file please. You are probably overriding some routes.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you try to append a name to your route a call it with route name?

Like this:

`Route::get('{slug}', 'ArticleController@viewArticle')->name('view.article');`

and in your Blade file create the anchor with:

`<a href="route('view.article')"`

Comment: Thanks for answer, still that same problem. I have views structure like this:

/views
 - admin
- article
- layouts
... etc

i tried add this for example in my views/layout/master.blade.php and I added:

<li><a href="{{ route('view.article', 'example-article-123') }}">Example article 123</a></li>

and that works fine as expected and it shows my views/article/index.blade.php with article content, but now images not loads and wysiwyg editor and file upload in my admin panel not working too.

Comment: Can you please check your console for errors ? If something don't load there must be some errors around, could you check also laravel log?

Comment: The problem isn't that anchor route don't show itself. The problem is - how to create SEO friendly links that will works (not anchor by URL::to() or etc.). I want to create all links (for galleries, posts, articles etc) like here http://cdn3.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/settingspermalink.png in "Post name" example. As you know - when you add at the end of route files something like this Route::get('{slug}', 'ArticleController@viewArticle'); you can match literally all. All system works fine, but I have to create all links SEO friendly not like /gallery/some-title etc.

Comment: I think wordpress stores special rewrite rules in database for that kind of links and checks for pattern and then redirects to controller/action. So, it is possible to do that without this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what you want, because you said some assets don't work, and now you want conditional routing to your controllers. Yes, you should use pattern matching, if you dive into wp code you can check their logic and implement something alike.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using route names, just use `url()` helper:

```
{{ url('some-title-for-article') }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used that for creating links. But that gives me an error after clicking on it because routes or htaccess are not configured to process that type of url

Comment: That's not related to the URL building, it's a web server issue. You need to use correct config for a web server. For example, you could try config from [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/).

Comment: Thanks. I use artisan build in server and I run application from command (php artisan serve), and I installed it from composer from official documentation. Everything wokrs fine, I just want URL like wordpress has, SEO friendly, it is possible to do that over routes, or it is better to do this in htaccess?